# Как обнулить counter и totalItems у плагина item-quantity-dropdown?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="iqdropdown menu-open" id="iqdropdown-2">
  <p class="iqdropdown-selection">Сколько гостей</p>
  <div class="iqdropdown-menu">
  
    <div class="iqdropdown-menu-option" data-id="item1">
      <p class="iqdropdown-item">Взрослые</p>
      <div class="iqdropdown-item-controls">
        <button class="button-decrement empty">
          <i class="icon-decrement"></i>
        </button>
        <span class="counter">0</span>
        <button class="button-increment">
          <i class="icon-decrement icon-increment"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="iqdropdown-menu-option" data-id="item2">
      <p class="iqdropdown-item">Дети</p>
      <div class="iqdropdown-item-controls">
        <button class="button-decrement empty">
          <i class="icon-decrement"></i>
        </button>
        <span class="counter">0</span>
        <button class="button-increment">
          <i class="icon-decrement icon-increment"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="iqdropdown-menu-option" data-id="item3">
      <p class="iqdropdown-item">Младенцы</p>
      <div class="iqdropdown-item-controls">
        <button class="button-decrement empty">
          <i class="icon-decrement"></i>
        </button>
        <span class="counter">0</span>
        <button class="button-increment">
          <i class="icon-decrement icon-increment"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="iqdropdown-buttons">
      <button class="iqdropdown-button_clean" id="iqdropdown-button_clean-2">очистить</button>
      <button class="iqdropdown-button_apply" id="iqdropdown-button_apply">применить</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Пробовал так

```
$('.iqdropdown-button_clean').on('click', function(element, totalItems) {
  var elem = element.target.id;
  var idPostfix = elem.slice(-2);
  var dropdownId = '#iqdropdown'+idPostfix; // #iqdropdown-2
  var counters = $(dropdownId).find('.counter');
  $.each(counters, function(key, value){
    console.log(key, value); 
    value.val(0); // Uncaught TypeError: value.val is not a function
  });

  $(dropdownId).find('.iqdropdown-selection').text('Сколько гостей');
  $(dropdownId).find('.iqdropdown-selection').val(0);

  totalItems = 0;
  console.log('totalItems: ' + totalItems); // totalItems: 0

});
```

в консоли получаю Uncaught TypeError: value.val is not a function

Comment: $(value).val(0);. Сделайте так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте так.

```
$(value).val(0);
```

В js нет val. Это сеттер из jQuery.

Comment: Так ошибки нет, но значение не обнуляется

Comment: Потому что существует другой код который не даёт это сделать.